# In what sense does Sylow theory determine "local structure" of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, sylow-theory

I'm reviewing some group theory with Alperin and Bell's Groups and Representations, and they chose to title the chapter containing the Sylow theorems, $p$-groups and compositions series by **Local Structure**. To preface the chapter they write

> "In many branches of mathematics, it is profitable to study an issue by somehow “localizing” with respect to a given prime number. In this chapter, we adapt this doctrine to group theory by studying finite groups through their subgroups of prime-power order. This notion of looking at the “local structure” of finite groups has proven to be very powerful."

In so far as I understood my first encounter with Sylow theory, we're essentially leveraging the properties of prime numbers to make claims about the properties of groups with prime power orders. Is there an intuitive way to understand why a mathematician might informally refer to this as local structure, or to localizing with respect to a prime? Or is it just because $p$-Sylow subgroups are "substructures" of a larger group $G$ and hence one can view studying the components as being a local property of $G$?

Comment: This is open to interpretation. For example, a finite group is nilpotent if and only if it is the direct product of its $p$-Sylow subgroups. This is a bit like a "local-global" result. I don't see a "localisation" though, like $S^{-1}R$ is the localisation for a ring $R$ with respect to a multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $R$. For a prime ideal $P$ in $R$, the localisation at $P$ is when we take $S=R\setminus P$. And in $R=\Bbb Z$, $P=(p)$ for a prime number $p$. But for groups?

Comment: In general, I'd say this is analogous to localization in the sense that you are looking at some proper piece of the group (a $p$-Sylow subgroup) in order to obtain results about the whole group. When you localize a commutative ring at a prime ideal, you are throwing away most ideals and looking at a specific chain. At least, that's how I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks, I like that answer after letting it percolate @DietrichBurde